# How to delete column Data, not column from excel in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I want to delete column data from a particular column, not column , column number will be dynamic ..

suppose an excel has 10 columns , and if I give 3 as input then on button click it should delete column 3 data....same way input may be 1,2,3,4,5....

how to start with this, can any one please help me in this...

Comment: show what you've tried ...

Comment: Why dont you try writting update query and bind dictionary linked with column numbers? Like for example...
Dictionary<int, string> int will contain column number and string will contain column name. later on whenever user will select the value from dropdown delete data by executing update statement and as you will be having the name of column you can simply write update tblname set columnname = null. as simple as that

Comment: @NisargShah can you please post some sample code, it will be better for understanding, theoretically i got it, how to implement it is still a probs..

Comment: @Deadlock I have never worked with Excel. Nor do i do coding. So sorry, I won't be able to help you with that part.